# URL rewrite in httpd

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I have use httpd server in my embedded board for display webpages. I have used CGI for display content on webpages. that page display from cgi and its url like "**ipaddress/cgi-bin/web page name**". I did not want to display cgi-bin in URL means I want to overwrite URL.

I already searched on net for this problem but i did not understand how to solve it. busy box httpd used

I have also found some Apache httpd server link but i did not understand

so plz help me.

Answer (score 0):

You need the following directives in `.htaccess` or your `VirtualHost` configuration:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/calculator\.php$ /cgi-bin/calculator.php [L]
```

The script `calculator.php` is just an example.

If all your php scripts are under `cgi-bin` and you want to rewrite them all using one directive then you can do:

```
RewriteRule ^/(.*)\.php$ /cgi-bin/$1.php [L]
```

Comment: thanks for quick reply. Now I have know about httpd.c file its busy box httpd . so rewrite engine functionality its not work